# why typescript does not show error when the lastName was a number?

Tags: typescript

trying to learn typescript, like the type check of typescript, just wondering
why the tsc can not detect the lastName is a number in the following case? thanks,

```
class Student {
  constructor(public firstName, public lastName ) {
  }
}

interface Person {
  firstName : string;
  lastName : string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
  return "hello, " + person
}

var user = new Student("Jane", 123)

console.log('user', user)
console.log('user.lastName is', typeof user.lastName)

console.log(greeter(user))
```

Comment: Because `Student` doesn't implement `Person`

Comment: but when user is used in greeter(user), it did not detect that the object's lastName is a number, the interface Person is expecting a string, right?

Answer (score 1):

In your class `Student`, the implicit type of the two properties is `any`:

```
class Student {
  constructor(public firstName, public lastName) {
  }
}
```

... is equivalent to:

```
class Student {
  public firstName: any;
  public lastName: any;
  // Here the constructor
}
```

Therefore, instances of the class `Student` are compatible to `Person`, because `any` is compatible to `string`.

An instance `user` can be created with a string and a number, because of the type `any`:

```
let user = new Student("Jane", 123)
```

... Then, you can write wrong code:

```
let p: Person;
p = user; // wrong code here
```

The type `any` is a way to disable type checking. Use it if you know what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I change the Student class to have string, so I got an error message in this line:

Comment: here is updated code:https://jsfiddle.net/gko4kwe6/, got an error:hello2.ts(15,32): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. but the line:console.log(greeter(user)) still no error

Comment: @AngeloC The wrong line: `var user = new Student("Jane", 123)` doesn't create an implicit type `StudentBis` with a `lastName` of type `number`. It declares a variable `user` of type `Student` (but with a buggy code). And then, a variable of type `Student` is compatible to the type `Person`.